# How to get the column number by passing column name in Java

Tags: java

In excel rows numbers start from '1' and continues and column number(id) start from A and continues like A,B,..Z,AA,AB...AZ,...ABX,.... 
now if we pass the input as 'A' output should be 1,
we we pass input as 'Z' output is 26, like wise if we pass any input (like AX, BCS) Java should return respective column number.
Could some one help me to get the algorithm in Java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at `CellReference` API of POI [CellReference](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/util/CellReference.html#convertColStringToIndex(java.lang.String)). `convertColStringToIndex()` should return you zero based index.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply tread it as a numeric System with the base of 26. Based on this you could simply use the mathematical correct way to determine the new value in a base 10 system like this:

```
public class Test
{
    private static final int sub = 64;
    private static final int base = 26;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println(getNumber("AD"));
    }

    private static int getNumber(String input) {
        int sum = 0;
        for(int i = 0;i<input.length();++i) {
            int representation = input.charAt(i);
            representation -= Test.sub;
            int value = (int) (representation * Math.pow(Test.base, input.length()-i-1));
            sum += value;
        }
        return sum;
    }
}
```